# java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I use glide 3.7.0,and have a crash in more phone:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@4473ee08 (pid=8376) when registering receiver android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy@436cd370
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.registerReceiver(ActivityManagerProxy.java:2492)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1543)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1511)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1505)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.register(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.onStart(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStart(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java)
    at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStart(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5217)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

What can I do?

Comment: May bi this error come.....With Image size.. big......

Comment: If you are using broadcast or services then make sure you have define it in manifest and also set permissions for the task which you are using like for internet and location and all